# Clearing input text failure

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am making a chat system, and when the user chats, it clears the input. The variable `msg` is the text that the user typed in.

```
let msg = document.querySelector("input").value;
```

I assumed that `msg = "";` would work for clearing the input, but it didn't. But for some reason `document.querySelector("input").value = "";` worked. Aren't they exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property of an input element is actually a *getter/setter*, similar to the `innerHTML` of elements. When you assign to the property, the setter runs and sets the state of the element in the DOM. When you get the property by accessing `.value`, the getter runs and retrieves the state of the element in the DOM.

In order to set a new value, you have to get the setter to run, and that requires assigning to the property, eg

```
document.querySelector("input").value = "";
```

Elements aside, reassigning a variable *by itself* will never have any side effects, in almost all situations. No matter what you're doing, `msg = ''` *alone* won't do anything unless `msg` is used later.

Answer (score 1):

No not same  msg assigns only value not element.
If u said `let msg = document.querySelector("input")` and `msg.value="";` it would work because msg is element here. In your code msg is value ( not element's value).